# javascript "if else" wont go in else when condition is not met

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, focus

I have an input text and an empty label in html

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="hsDetailsForm-name">Denumire</label>
    <input id="hsDetailsForm-name" type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="hydroStation.name" placeholder="Obligatoriu" required ng-blur="validationObliga()" autofocus/>
    <label id="obliga"></label>
</div>
```

and here is the function in js

```
$scope.validationObliga = function () {
    var value = $.trim($("hsDetailsForm-name").val());

    if (value == "") {
        $('#obliga').html("Campul este obligatoriuu!").css("color", "red");
    } else {
        $('#obliga').html("");
    }
}
```

`ng-blur` works and when empty it writes "Campul este obligatoriuu!" in red, however when you type something in the text field and focus out of it, it still says that, it doesnt change the label to "". Why don't it go in the else ?

Comment: You're not using AngularJS here, you're just using jQuery. This is the main reason most of the developers don't recommend including jQuery in AngularJS app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error here is you've missed `#` of the id selector.

Although, adding `#` in the selector will solve your problem, I won't recommend you to use jQuery here, use AngularJS as follow

Controller:

```
$scope.validationObliga = function () {
    var value = $scope.hydroStation.name.trim();

    $scope.showMessage = value === "";
};
```

View:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="hsDetailsForm-name">Denumire</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="hydroStation.name" placeholder="Obligatoriu" required ng-blur="validationObliga()" autofocus/>
    <label ng-show="showMessage" class="error">Campul este obligatoriuu!</label>
    <!--   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^                     Add this --->
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.error {
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You missed the anchor here; should be...

```
var value = $.trim($("#hsDetailsForm-name").val());
```

... so that you look for an element with `id` equal to `hsDetailsForm-name`. As it stands, you look for *an element* `hsDetailsForm-name` - and there's none. As result, jQuery element is empty, its val() is `undefined`, and `$.trim(undefined)` results in an empty string.